# How to grant access to Youtube Reporting API for a google service account?

Tags: api, youtube, service-accounts, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to access YouTube Reporting API with a service account. But I am getting a 403 forbidden when trying to do `youtubeReporting.jobs().list().execute()`.

YouTube Reporting API clearly supposed Server-to-server interaction.

Do I need to grant access to Youtube Reporting API for a google service account? If so, how?

FYI : I am not using google app domain.

Answer (score 1):

You could [create](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) service credentials in the google console, but those credentials won't fix your issue. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization),

> The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Reporting API and YouTube Analytics API do not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will generate an error.

It is p counter-intuitive-- (not to mention hard to locate)-- this info esp. since conceptually related YT APIs utilize service accounts, see [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/oauth2_for_service_accounts), and the reporting api actions wouldn't seem to need to be associated w/ a specific user account.

Unfortunately, if you use a service account for the Youtube Reporting API you will still end up with a 403 unauthorized caller error.

Instead, [create](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=tommy-boy&pli=1) and use web client google credentials. Store and use the token generated from the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the Cloud Platform Console. See https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158841?hl=en for details